# Vuetify data-table pass array to v-slot to populate a v-select inside the table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Using Vue 2+

In one of the columns in my data table I have a `v-select` with `multiple` prop, so it can take an array of values to populate the `v-select` as well as populate an array with all the selected values.

And I can't get it to work. In fact when I try and simply pass an array to the select it won't display anything.

This is my data table:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  show-select
  :items="returnProducts"
  item-key="id"
  v-model="selectedProducts"
>
```

And then one element in the `returnProducts` array looks like this:

```
{ 
  "product_title": "With Inventory - something", 
  "id": 1933709, 
  "sku": "15xx", 
  "handle_fulfillments": [ 
    { "id": 24, 
      "product_id": 1933709, 
      "auth_id": 4774
    },
    { "id": 28, 
      "product_id": 1933710, 
      "auth_id": 4774
    }  
  ]
}
```

The column I'm trying to populate with the v-selects looks like this:

```
  <template 
    v-slot:item.handle_fulfillments="{ item }"
  >
    <v-select
      v-model="item.handle_fulfillments"
      :items="marketplaces"
      dense
      label="Select Marketplace"
      multiple
      @change="productChange(item)"
    >
    </v-select>
  </template>
```

And as `handle_fulfillments` is a nested array, it just barfs and doesn't display anything. Nor does it throw an error of any kind.

How can I pass and display an array of values into a vuetify data-table v-slot

Answer (score 2):

You are returning an *object*, so in your `v-select` you should add `return-object`.

Also your are missing `item-text` and `item-value` that will handle the data in your **v-select**.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      selectedProducts:'',
      fulfillments:[],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'TITLE',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'product_title',
        },
        { text: 'ID', value: 'id' },
        { text: 'SKU', value: 'sku' },
        { text: 'HANDLE FULFILLMENTS', value: 'handle_fulfillments' },
      ],
      returnProducts: [
        { 
          "product_title": "With Inventory - something", 
          "id": 1933709, 
          "sku": "15xx", 
          "handle_fulfillments": [ 
            { "id": 24, 
              "product_id": 1933709, 
              "auth_id": 4774
            },
            { "id": 28, 
              "product_id": 1933710, 
              "auth_id": 4774
            }  
          ]
        }
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      show-select
      :items="returnProducts"
      item-key="id"
      v-model="selectedProducts"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.handle_fulfillments="{ item }">
          <v-select
            v-model="fulfillments"
            :items="item.handle_fulfillments"
            item-text="id"
            item-value="product_id"
            dense
            label="Select Marketplace"
            multiple
            @change="productChange(item)"
            return-object
          >
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
      
      <h4>Result</h4>
      Selected Data:{{ fulfillments }}<br>
      <div v-for="data in fulfillments">
        ID:{{ data.id }}<br>
        Product ID:{{ data.product_id }}<br>
        Auth ID:{{ data.auth_id }}<br>
      </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```